# Javaのmapとcsvを組み合わせて，csvのほしい個所を出力するプログラムを作っております．

Tags: java

質問失礼いたします．

例えばなんですが

```
Map<String, String> oldMap = new HashMap<>();;
oldMap.put("suzuki", aiueo);

Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();;
newMap.put("suzuki", kkkkk);
```

のような値がmapで定義されていたとして

また，csvがあり(縦横は行列の番号，name, old, newはヘッダーです． 1x1は1行目の一列目としています)

```
  1 name 2 old 3 new 4
1 suzuki aiueo kkkkk konnitiha
2 seigo  aiueo ttttt kontiwa
3 suzuki kkkkk aiueo majimaji
4 hukko  ttttt sssss ohohohoho
```

のようになっているとき，oldMapとnewMapのkeyが等しくて，かつ，oldのvalue(csvでいう1x2)とnewのvalue(csvでいうと1x3)の値が等しいとき，konnitihaを出力したいのですが
このようなことは実現可能でしょうか？

とにかくcsvの内容を二次元配列にしてやってみたのですが，なかなか手ごわくて困っております．

もしよろしければお力をお貸しください・・・．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV ファイルの内容を連想配列(HashMap)にします。

###### selectColumn.java

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class selectColumn {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // read CSV file
    HashMap<List<String>, String> tbl = readCSVFile("data.csv");

    // set the keys for selection
    Map<String, String> oldMap = new HashMap<>();;
    oldMap.put("suzuki", "aiueo");
    Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();;
    newMap.put("suzuki", "kkkkk");

    // select
    oldMap.forEach(
      (key, value) -> {
        if (newMap.containsKey(key)) {
          String matched = tbl.get(Arrays.asList(key, value, newMap.get(key)));
          System.out.println(matched == null ? "None matched" : matched);
        }
      });
  }

  // readCSVFile returns HashMap instance
  //   key: first, second and third column (name, old, new)
  // value: 4th column
  public static HashMap<List<String>, String> readCSVFile(String pathToCsv) {
    HashMap<List<String>, String> rows = new HashMap<>();
    try {
      File file = new File(pathToCsv);
      BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      csvReader.readLine(); // skip header line
      String row;
      while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] items = row.split(",");
        rows.put(
          Collections.unmodifiableList(
            Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(items, 0, items.length-1))),
          items[items.length-1]);
      }
      csvReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }

    return rows;
  }
}
```

###### data.csv

```
name,old,new,
suzuki,aiueo,kkkkk,konnitiha
seigo,aiueo,ttttt,kontiwa
suzuki,kkkkk,aiueo,majimaji
hukko,ttttt,sssss,ohohohoho
```

###### 実行結果

```sh
$ javac selectColumn.java && java selectColumn
konnitiha
```